# convert timestamp in UTC to users local time javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a time stamp like such **1443728852**, how do i convert this to the users local time. I have this:

```
time = new Date(1443728852);
alert(time.toLocaleTimeString());
```

but this is giving me the UTC/GMT time not my local time like EST for example?

Answer (score 0):

By default date object gives date and time in users local timezone. One more thing is that Date object required timestamp in milliseconds so you need to multiply it by 1000.

```
time = new Date(1443728852 * 1000);
alert(time.toLocaleTimeString());
```